# Installation of WPS from Falathub stuck

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 20.04, desktop-environments, flatpak

Installation was stuck here

```
Looking for matches…

com.wps.Office permissions:
    ipc      network              pulseaudio      x11
    dri      file access [1]      tags [2]

    [1] /media, /run/media, xdg-documents, xdg-download, xdg-pictures,
    xdg-videos
    [2] proprietary


    ID                Branch    Op    Remote    Download
 1. [\] com.wps.Office    stable    i     flathub   17.4 MB / 252.2 MB

Installing… ██▊                   14%  544.8 kB/s  03:16 >
```

I tried installing WPS from Flathub. I followed their guides and everything.

Suddenly, the installation was stuck here. It's almost an hour.

What do I do?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead: https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I'm sorry, my bad. Okay.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! If you're not on a data-capped network or similar, have you tried cancelling the install and retrying?